# What was in the Holy Incense of the ancient Hebrews of Exodus 30:34–38?

Tags: mesorah-tradition

In Exodus 30:34–38, we read the following:

> 34 And the Lord said to Moses: “Take **sweet spices, stacte and onycha and galbanum, and pure frankincense with these sweet spices**; there shall be equal amounts of each. 35 You shall make of these an incense, a compound according to the art of the perfumer, salted, pure, and holy. 36 And you shall beat some of it very fine, and put some of it before the Testimony in the tabernacle of meeting where I will meet with you. It shall be most holy to you. 37 But as for the incense which you shall make, you shall not make any for yourselves, according to its composition. It shall be to you holy for the Lord. 38 Whoever makes any like it, to smell it, he shall be cut off from his people.” - [Exodus 30:34–38.](http://biblia.com/bible/nkjv/Exodus%2030.34-38)

My question is quite simply. For a non speaking Hebrew person like myself what were the traditional ingredients of the Holy Incense as it was revealed to Moses by G_d, according to ancient Jewish tradition?

Also are there any ancient Jewish writers that wrote about adding other substances to this incense? If so what were they?

Comment: One place to look is the talmud, tractate kritute page 6b.

Comment: I have actually seen a box with bottles of spices that claim to be the ingredients of the incense. I do not have access to it now but will look tonight or after Shabbos (bli neder)

Comment: @sabbahillel The Temple Institute sells a partial mixture of the k'toret -- obviously making the full thing is forbidden.